# Check telephonyManager.getDeviceId() returns a Real value or not

Tags: android, imei

**Requirement**

One android device one account. To restrict user creating multiple accounts in a single device.

**What I had done**

During Log in, With the help of telephonyManager.getDeviceId() I am getting the IMEI number of an android device. Then I am checking this with all IMEI number stored in my server Database.
But after impementing

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String IMEINo = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

I got many **IMEI** numbers that's fake. 
For example I checked in https://www.imei24.com for "272052651704884".
The result was "Given IMEI 272052651704884 is not correct. Control amount is false. The last digit of the IMEI number is generated based on Luhna formula."

After doing many research I came to know that if you are cloaning the App using Parallel Space or any othrt such, telephonyManager.getDeviceId() returns a fake value.

After 7 long months I found a solution to this problem. That is Lunh Algorithm, which perform some calculation and tells weather it is a valid IMEI or not.

**What I Need:** A suggestion for weather I should blindly rely on The Lunh Algorithm or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this it will works. I found real IMEI number with `getDeviceId()`

```
     TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return;
                }

                String IMEI_Number = null;
                if (telephonyManager != null) {
                    IMEI_Number = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
                }
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    String Imei0Id = null;
                    if (telephonyManager != null) {
                        Imei0Id = telephonyManager.getDeviceId(0);
                    }
                    if (null != Imei0Id && !Imei0Id.equals("000000000000000")) {
                        IMEI_Number = Imei0Id;
                    }


}
```

Comment: I have done all of these things but running the app on parallel space, it returns a false IMEI number

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Use an immutable universally unique identifier (UUID). A UUID represents a 128-bit value.

```
UUID.randomUUID().toString()
```